# Jenkins Groovy pipeline, variable adds a newline and breaks curl statement

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job, and part of the code looks like this:

```
def version = sh returnStdout: true, script: """ #!/bin/sh                    
find  src/*/*/ -name *.ear |  grep -Eo \'[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\' 
"""
sh "echo $version"


def imageVersion = sh returnStdout: true, script: """
#!/bin/sh                    
curl -k -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api:${api_key}'  https://artifactory.xxx.com/api/search/latestVersion\\?g=com.xxx.bwce&a=billing-app-v1&v=$version-SNAPSHOT&repos=libs-snapshot-local
"""
```

And I noticed that during the execution, this curl statement is broken at this variable replacement.

here is how the output looks from Jenkins console log.

```
+ echo 1.0.6
1.0.6
[Pipeline] sh

+ curl -k -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:**** 'https://artifactory.xxx.com/api/search/latestVersion?g=com.xxx.bwce&a=billing-app-v1&v=1.0.6'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    23    0    23    0     0     34      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    34
+ '-SNAPSHOT&repos=libs-snapshot-local'
```

Please suggest if there is a way to fix this. I am not sure why its adding a newline in the curl statement, but echo shows no newline in it.

Comment: Try `version = version.trim()` immediately after your `def version =...` line

Comment: wow, that simple trick did it.
thanks

Comment: Cool  added it as an answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim the newline off the end of `version` by adding the line

```
version = version.trim()
```

After your `def version =` line